# 安定結婚問題の「絶望の定理」の証明

Tags: グラフ理論

グラフ理論において、[安定結婚問題](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%AE%89%E5%AE%9A%E7%B5%90%E5%A9%9A%E5%95%8F%E9%A1%8C)があります。

ある２部グラフの特定の安定マッチングにおいて、ペアを作れなかった人(たとえば男性数>女性数でのマッチングで存在)は、どのような安定マッチングにおいてもペアが作れないことを、安定結婚問題における「絶望の定理」と呼ぶらしいのですが、この定理の証明を見つけられずにいます。

証明自体、もしくは証明のソースをご存知の方はいらっしゃいますでしょうか。

Comment: その「絶望の定理」は `Rural Hospital Theorem` と呼ばれているものではないでしょうか？ この記事で確認してみて下さい。[安定マッチングのおはなし](http://s-circle-sb.blogspot.jp/2014/07/blog-post.html)

Comment: その通りで、Rural Hospital Theorem が、英語での正式称名の様子です。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@argus さんの情報を情報をもとに、調べて行った結果、

https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/37942/37273
(man-oriented な Gale-Shapley で man-optimal (最大元)かつ woman-pessimal (最小元)が得られる)
と
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/978729/260854
(1. optimal, 任意の matching, pessimal の３つの間で、パートナーの有無は、単調増加(語弊あり？)する
2. ある参加者のパートナーの有無が stable matching 間で変わったとすると、1. の結果から玉突き事故のようなことが起こってしまうので、そんなことは起こらない)

によって、説明できそうでした。